# How do I emulate transaction behaviour in PHP with third party APIs?

Tags: php, api, transactions

Say for example I am trying to initialize a calendar with recurring events.

```
try {
  $api->createCalendar()
  $api->createCalendarSettings()
  $api->createRecurringEvent()
} catch (Exception $exception) {

}
```

I want these 3 calls to act as a unit. If any one of them fails, previously successful actions must be undone. Is there a smart way of doing this other than to call the reverse action for every action in the catch block? The problem with doing that is that I don't know which actions already succeeded and the reverse actions might also blow up.

Comment: php has no "transactions". That's purely a database concept. if you want to "rollback" in php, you'll have to do undo each step yourself. and consider that many things WON'T be undoable. e.g. `unlink('foo.txt')` can't just be magically "undone".